# Does pumping a septic system disrupt the tank's ecology?

Tags: plumbing, septic

We are the original owners of a 4BR/2.5 Bath home that has been mainly occupied by 2 people over 14 years. (Occasionally 3 people for short periods of time, less than 1 year)

We have never had the cover dug/removed for the system / tank to be pumped.

I've gone by the "old school ecology" premise that if it is breaking down the intake effectively you should "leave it alone".  Once you start pumping regularly, you have disrupted an effective ecological working  system.

Is this a misnomer and a "plumber's tale"  or should I subscribe to the "pumpers tale" of thinking?

Answer (score 4):

It is recommended that septic tanks be pumped every 3-5 years, having said that it is not always necessary depending on the usage of the tank. You could simply check the sludge level in the tank to see if it requires a pump out. Leaving the tank without checking it is not a good idea as even though it may seem to be working it may be allowing solids/suspended solids to enter the distribution field, which in turn will case it to fail prematurely.

In regard to your other question yes it does disrupt the ecology of the tank when it is pumped if the whole tank is emptied but this will right itself and if you abstain from using harsh chemicals that drain to the septic this time frame will be reduced.

[Pdf on septic care](http://www.nesc.wvu.edu/pdf/ww/septic/septic_tank2.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You know your yearly usage,and age of septic.Cost little to have pumped. Expensive to replace. Mine is getting older and have it done every year. If buying home, seller should have it pumped as part of the closing. Septics need to be kept up. Not left alone for years. Peaple do put the wrong items down them.